# How a suspicious links are being added to my asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, security, malware, malware-detection, antimalware

I have a simple asp.net website. Recently, I have noticed it adds one div with an anchor tag to an external. I have also noticed another link of apparent jQuery file from a thirdparty site that obviously is not a jQuery at all.
So when clicked anywhere on my site - another tab is opened to redirect to the third party site. I have checked within the code for any clue of the urls that are being added - with no luck. Following are the suspicious div and url. Will be much appreciated if anyone can suggest anything - how it is being injected or how I can find it ?

[image]

```
<div id="div642028" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 99999999;"><a href="http://c822c1b63853ed273b89687ac505f9fa.onepro.club/redirect?u=aHR0cHM6Ly91cy51c2FkYXkuYml6Lz91dG1fbWVkaXVtPTYyMTQ0MzY3OGNlNzI1YzE1NjkxMjgzMTdlNDA3ZDg4ODI2NWVkZGUmdXRtX2NhbXBhaWduPW15Y2Ft" target="_blank" style="display: block; width:100%; height: 100%; cursor: default"></a></div>
```

[image]

```
https://abu.usaday.biz/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```

I can see some reference for these urls as potential malware reporting :

Ref:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/5bf7d472c484efae33e45e33373c06cf515508afa7f76782d5016cd1fc8f0df3/detection
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/6ab9b7111a9015aec417d92de6b93c659230f25db64e479fdc14f4676fc6f081/community
https://hybrid-analysis.com/sample/957448b513c4403ae13f7d0d6c19c70f13c92a1f9664e41f39521dd51e80adda

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but had founded it in my hacked jquery file
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here with one site. Found out the injection code was on jquery-2.x.min.js as you can see here:

[image]

**and**

[image]
Hope this helps!